# acyclic decomposition of hypergraphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, data-analysis, hypergraphs

The following is from the paper  *[Arboricity: An acyclic hypergraph decomposition problem motivated by database theory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X11003349)* by Yeow Meng Chee, Lijun Ji, Andrew Lim, Anthony K.H. Tung:

[image]

[image]

**Question:** For an arbitrary finite hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$, does $\mathcal{H}$ always have a finite acyclic decomposition? Are there any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arbitrary finite hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$ put each edge in a separate component, that is, take $\mathcal{A}_i = \{A_i\}$. 
All such one-hyperedge graphs have all degrees equal to one, so they are acyclic.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$